# VBScript getting values from a form

Tags: html, css, vbscript

I have a simple form

```
<div id="stylized" class="myform">
 <form id="mysmartform">
 <h1>CourtSmart Server Status</h1>
 <p>Are the servers running?</p>

<label>Yes
 <span class="small">All Servers Are Running</span>
 </label>
 <input type="radio" name="formradio" id="stylized" value="yes" />

<label>No
 <span class="small">We Have A Problem</span>
 </label>
 <input type="radio" name="formradio" id="stylized" value="no" />

<label>eMail
    <span class="small"></span>
</label>
<select name="formemail" size="1">
    <option value="someone@example.com" selected="selected">someone@example.com</option>
    <option value="someone@example.com">someone@example.com</option>
    <option value="someone@example.com">someone@example.com</option>
    <option value="someone@example.com">someone@example.com</option>
    <option value="someone@example.com">someone@example.com</option>
</select>


<button type="submit" id="sendReport">Send Status Report</button>
 <div class="spacer"></div>
```

Using VBScript I want to access the values for the selected radio button and the selected email address and just do a simple MsgBox to display it

Comment: Why VBScript? Is that HTML page embedded in an application or macro?

Comment: Well I can accept JavaScript if you can tell me how to do this WSHShell.Run "wscript """ & Path & "NotLogHeat1parm.vbs"" """ & Path & """"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Option Explicit
Dim objIE : Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

objIE.Visible = False
objIE.Navigate "file://C:/form.html"
Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4
WScript.Sleep 100
Loop

Dim value_running
Dim value_problem
Dim result

value_running = objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(0).value
value_problem = objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("input").item(1).value

If StrComp(value_running,"yes")=0 Then
    result = 0
ElseIf StrComp(value_problem,"yes")=0 Then
    result = 1
Else
    result = -1
End If

Wscript.Echo Result
```

Comment: Just regular VBS, but I think it could be adapted to HTA.

Comment: What was the error?  What was your command line to run the script?  I just saved your HTML as a local file, then ran `wscript.exe extract.vbs`.  I didn't see any errors.

Comment: Line 6. Do Until objIE.ReadyState = 4. "The system interface is unknown". I am using IE9 but need to make sure it works on all versions of IE

Comment: I think that has something to do with your system or your browser settings.  Take a look at this other [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014815/how-do-you-get-watin-to-work-on-windows-server-2008-with-ie8).  Look at the first two answers.  Are you running as administrator in your shell?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean running a vbscript, putting some GUI up in IE and getting the value's, here is an example

```
Set web = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application") 
If web Is Nothing Then 
  msgbox("Error while loading Internet Explorer") 
  Wscript.Quit 
Else 
  with web 
    .Width = 300 
    .Height = 175 
    .Offline = True 
    .AddressBar = False 
    .MenuBar = False 
    .StatusBar = False 
    .Silent = True 
    .ToolBar = False 
    .Navigate "about:blank" 
    .Visible = True 
  end with 
End If 

'Wait for the browser to navigate to nowhere 
Do While web.Busy 
  Wscript.Sleep 100 
Loop 

'Wait for a good reference to the browser document 
Set doc = Nothing 
Do Until Not doc Is Nothing 
  Wscript.Sleep 100 
  Set doc = web.Document 
Loop 

'Write the HTML form 
doc.Write "Give me a name<br><form><input type=text name=name ><input type=button name=submit id=submit value='OK' onclick='javascript:submit.value=""Done""'></form>" 
Set oDoc = web.Document 
Do Until oDoc.Forms(0).elements("submit").Value <> "OK" 
  Wscript.Sleep 100 
  If web Is Nothing or Err.Number <> 0 Then 
    msgbox "Window closed" 
    Wscript.Quit 
  End If 
Loop 
name = oDoc.Forms(0).elements("name").value 
oDoc.close 
set oDoc = nothing 
web.quit 
set web = nothing 
Wscript.echo "Hello " & name
```